# Chrome extension: match opened tab to loaded tab in background.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension. I need to pass a variable to the tab that is opened, and then have that variable be available when the tab's webpage has completed loading. I need to be able to uniquely match the opened tab with the loaded tab.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    url = "my_url";
    unique_id = "some id"; // I need to pass this on
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: url }, function(tab){});

    // I cannot use any global vars because this function actually loops and opens lots of tabs.

});

// Called when page has finished loading
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(tab) {

    if(tab.frameId == 0){ 
       // I need to identify the tab (unique_id) that was created in chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener()
       // tab.url won't work because it's different if the orginal url was redirected
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) have tab IDs which are `unique within a browser session`.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    url = "my_url";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: url }, function(tab){
        unique_id = tab.id; // I need to pass this on
    });

});

// Called when page has finished loading
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {

    if(details.frameId == 0){ 
       unique_id = details.tabId;
    }

});
```

Comment: They ID's don't match. The first tab.id is the ID of the tab where the button is clicked. The second tabId is the ID of the newly created and loaded tab.

Comment: If you move "unique_id = tab.id;" inside the function(tab){} then it works.